# What dos count[i]++ mean

Tags: c, arrays

Hello I came across this explanation about Finding first non repeating number in an array.
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-string-find-its-first-non-repeating-character/
In this explanation ,  I did not understand what this means

```
count[*(str+i)]++;  or count[index]++;
```

Can anyone please help me understand this

Comment: You are incrementing the value at `count[index]` by 1... just look up what array access and incrementing is.

Comment: count[] is initialized to zero. The characters are being used as indexes to increment elements in count, creating a histogram, a count of the number of occurrences for each character value in str. This same hisotgram method is also used for the counting phase of a [counting / radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short version:**

`count[index]++` is shorthand for `count[index] = count[index] + 1`.

**Long version:**

The expression `i++` *evaluates* to the current value of `i`, and as a *side effect* increments the value stored in `i` by 1.  So given the code

```
int a = 1, b;
b = a++;
printf( "a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b );
```

the output would be

```
a = 2, b = 1
```

There is a corresponding prefix version `++i`; in this case, the expression evaluates to `i+1` and as a side effect increments `i` by 1, so

```
int a = 1, b;
b = ++a;
printf( "a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b );
```

gives the output

```
a = 2, b = 2
```

There are corresponding prefix and postfix `--` operators that subtract 1.

Note that expressions like

```
i++ * i++
i = i++
a[i] = i++
printf( "%d %d", i++, i++ )
```

all have *undefined behavior*, and will not give consistent results across platforms (or even across builds on the same platform).  With few exceptions, C does not guarantee that expressions are evaluated in any specific order, nor does it guarantee that side effects are applied immediately after an expression has been evaluated.

Comment: As you deleted your post I can answer here. It is not me who down-voted . In my opinion your answer was correct. Don;t worry. Be happy.:)

Answer (score 1):

1)
**count[index]++** is the post-fix notation i.e i++ will increment the value of i, but return the original value that i held before being incremented.

Also count[index]++ = count[index]+1  //incrementing value by 1.
here index is location.

2)
**count[*(str+i)]++***
 here (str+i) returns value stored at pointer location str+i whatever value of i is, and that acts as a index value to count.
Finally value count[(str+i)] gets incremented as explained above.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

`count[index]++;` means you are incrementing the value by one in the specific `index` in the array `count`.

If you don't understand arrays, or the shorthand symbols like `++` I'd recommend looking up documentation/tutorials on Arrays and Operators.